# Rspec Test Fail After Migrating from Sqlite to Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, rspec, database-cleaner

I'm using Cloud 9 + Ruby on Rails + Rspec + Capybara + FactoryGirl + DatabaseCleaner. Up until now, I've been using sqlite for development and ran across charting functionality that wouldn't work with sqlite. So I migrated over to using Postgresql.

Now when I run my rspec test, it fails. I can revert back to using sqlite and the test run just fine at that point.

Here is one of the errors I'm receiving:

```
Failures:

  2) Property creation has been completed successfully
     Failure/Error: @property = FactoryGirl.create(:property)

     ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:
       PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "properties" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_680868ce5b"
       DETAIL:  Key (property_type_id)=(1) is not present in table "property_types".
       : INSERT INTO "properties" ("address", "city", "state", "zip", "property_type_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `create'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
     # ./spec/features/property_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # PG::ForeignKeyViolation:
     #   ERROR:  insert or update on table "properties" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_680868ce5b"
     #   DETAIL:  Key (property_type_id)=(1) is not present in table "property_types".
     #   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
```

I think this error is happing because the property_type_id of 1 doesn't exists with an ID of 1 in the property_types table when it is created. Instead the ID for property_types is 2. It seems as if the ID column is not resetting back to 1 after each example.

Here's my rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!


ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before(:suite) { DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation) }
  config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction }
  config.before(:each, :js => true) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation }
  config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
  config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Here's the Database.yml file:

```
default: &default
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      pool: 5
      username: ubuntu
      password: xxxxxxxx
      template: template0

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
```

Here is one of the test that fail:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'Property' do

    describe 'creation' do

        it "has been completed successfully" do            
            @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)            
            login_as(@user, :scope => :user)  
            FactoryGirl.create(:property_type)
            @property = FactoryGirl.create(:property)
            visit new_property_path
            fill_in "property_address", with: @property.address
            fill_in "property_city", with: @property.city
            fill_in "property_state", with: @property.state
            fill_in "property_zip", with: @property.zip
            fill_in "property_units", with: @property.units  
            click_button "Save"  
            expect(@property.reload.address).to eq(@property.address)
            expect(@property.reload.city).to eq(@property.city)
            expect(@property.reload.state).to eq(@property.state)
            expect(@property.reload.zip).to eq(@property.zip)
            expect(@property.reload.units).to eq(@property.units)
    end
end
```

Here's the Property Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

   factory :property do
      address "111 Test Dr" 
      city "Test"
      state "TS"
      zip "999999"
      property_type_id 1
      user_id 1
   end
end
```

Here's the User Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

   factory :user do
        email "tester@tester.com"
        first_name "Test"
        last_name "Test"
        password "abcd1234"
        password_confirmation "abcd1234"       
   end
end
```

Here's the Property Type Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :property_type do
    name "Single Family"
  end
end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I've been researching this issue for several days.

Comment: You have foreign key constraint error. `PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "properties" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_680868ce5b"`. Could you post all the `migrations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Property Factory, the property_type_id is always referencing 1, which will raise foreign key error if it cannot be found in property_type table.

You can change it to use association if property has a relationship with property_type, and it will create property_type dynamically.

```
FactoryGirl.define do

   factory :property do
      address "111 Test Dr" 
      city "Test"
      state "TS"
      zip "999999"
      property_type
      user_id 1
   end
end
```

Or you can have a property_type record with id 1 persisted in test db.

Comment: Zhong, I've made your suggested changes which resolved the error that was initially shown here but now there are other errors. Here's what I've done so far. --Updated Property Factory to use associations. --Updated Property Type Factory to use associations. --Updated Property Model to have 'belongs_to :user' reference.    Failures:

  1) Property creation modification has been completed successfully
     Failure/Error: @property = current_user.properties.find(params[:id])
     
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Property with 'id'=3 [WHERE "properties"."user_id" = ?]

Comment: How do you create property record? `current_user.properties.create`? or `Properties.new`. It feels to me that property record does not have user_id.

Comment: `current_user.properties.create` would create property for `current_user`

Comment: Zhong. The issue is that the property record is being saved with a user_id of 4. However, the user_id that should be tied to the record is 3. There's something going on with the ID sequences not being reset.

Comment: In the test case, `FactoryGirl.create(:property)` tells me that you are creating property without specify the user, try `FactoryGirl.create(:property, user: @user)`

Comment: that did it Zhong! I'm just curious as to why the logged in user was not saved when the property record is created. Why do we have to specify the user on the FactoryGirl.create?

Comment: Because `@property = FactoryGirl.create(:property)` will create a new property with a new user (assume you defined user association in property factory). A more readable way to do it is `@user.properties.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:property))` . Both means these properties belong to @user.